# How do I fetch a new array onClick?

Tags: reactjs

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    meme: {},
    num: 6
  };
  this.APIURL = `http://meme.com/${this.state.num}`;
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(this.APIURL)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        this.setState({
          meme: data
        });
      }

      console.log(this.state.meme);
    });
}

nextPic = () => {
  if (this.state.num > this.state.meme.totalMemes) {
    this.setState({
      num: 1
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      num: this.state.num + 1
    });
    console.log(this.state.num);
  }
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.meme.title}</h1>
      <img key={this.state.num} src={this.state.meme.encodedurl} />
      <button onClick={this.nextPic}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This calls the api depending on this.state.num. How do I make it so that when nextPic() is called this.state.num + 1 is called? Right now this.state.num gets updated but it doesn't fetch the api again.

This is how the API looks :

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything in `nextPic()` that shows you are trying to fetch anything, try adding your `fetch()` block inside your function

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the fetch to a separate method which you call both in `componentDidMount` and in `nextPic`.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    meme: {},
    num: 6
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchMeme();
  }

  fetchMeme = () => {
    const url = `http://meme.com/${this.state.num}`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          meme: data
        });
      });
  };

  nextPic = () => {
    this.setState({
      num: this.state.num >= this.state.meme.totalMemes ? 1 : this.state.num + 1
    }, this.fetchMeme);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.meme.title}</h1>
        <img key={this.state.num} src={this.state.meme.encodedurl} />
        <button onClick={this.nextPic}>Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the api fetch call a function. try this:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    meme: {},
    num: 6
  };

}

componentDidMount() {
  fetchFromAPI(this.state.num);
}

let fetchFromAPI = (num)=>{

this.APIURL = `http://meme.com/${num}`;

   fetch(this.APIURL)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        this.setState({
          meme: data
        });
      }

      console.log(this.state.meme);
    });

}

nextPic = () => {
  if (this.state.num > this.state.meme.totalMemes) {
    this.setState({
      num: 1
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      num: this.state.num + 1
    });
    console.log(this.state.num);
  }
   fetchFromAPI(this.state.num);
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{this.state.meme.title}</h1>
      <img key={this.state.num} src={this.state.meme.encodedurl} />
      <button onClick={this.nextPic}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I did not test this, but looks like it will work.